# Assigning Retained Object to Unsafe Property

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am making a custom `UITableViewDataSource` and when I am assigning that datasource to the TableView I get the following error:

> "Assigning retained object to unsafe property; object will be released after assignment"

Here is my code which causes the **ERROR**:

```
 self.tableView.dataSource = [[ShoppingListDataSource alloc] initWithItems:_shoppingLists identifier:@"ShoppingListTableViewCell" configureCellBlock:^(ShoppingListTableViewCell *cell, ShoppingList *shoppingList) {

        [cell configure:shoppingList];

    }];
```

ShoppingListDataSource.h:

```
@import UIKit;

typedef void (^ConfigureCellBlock) (ShoppingListTableViewCell *cell, ShoppingList *shoppingList);

@interface ShoppingListDataSource : NSObject<UITableViewDataSource>

-(instancetype) initWithItems:(NSArray *) items identifier:(NSString *) identifier configureCellBlock:(ConfigureCellBlock) configureCellBlock;


@property (nonatomic,strong) NSArray *items;
@property (nonatomic,copy) NSString *identifier;
@property (nonatomic,copy) ConfigureCellBlock configureCellBlock;

@end
```

ShoppingListDataSource.m:

```
-(instancetype) initWithItems:(NSArray *)items identifier:(NSString *)identifier configureCellBlock:(ConfigureCellBlock)configureCellBlock
{
    self = [super init];

    self.identifier = identifier;
    self.items = items;
    self.configureCellBlock = configureCellBlock;

    return self;
}
```

My view controller inherits from UITableViewController.

Comment: Which line exactly is causing the error?

Comment: Sorry! Updated the question.

Comment: Just to be sure, which of the 3 lines in that code is causing the error? Most likely it's the first of the three, correct?

Comment: I have updated the question. It is the self.tableView.datasource line. Also, my view controller inherits from UITableViewController.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table views do not retain their data sources. They hold only a weak reference. When you do this:

```
self.tableView.dataSource = [[ShoppingListDataSource alloc] initWithItems:...
```

the only reference to this newly created object is `dataSource`. That means that when you hit the semicolon, the object will be released and `dataSource` will be set to nil.

You need to store this data source in a `strong` property, probably in your controller.

(As rmaddy points out, I'm looking at iOS 9 docs; in earlier versions, it was `assign`, which is even worse, but the same basic problem.)

Comment: Actually, `dataSource` is `assign` (pre iOS 9) so it won't be set to `nil` but instead remains pointing to the garbage. This error won't happen in iOS 9.

Comment: Right; but you should still get a warning (and of course wrong behavior, just no crash).

Comment: I suppose you might get a warning in iOS 9 but it would be a different warning since there in no longer an "unsafe property" in iOS 9.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rob and also @rmaddy! Yes you are right that was the issue. I moved it into a strong property and now it works! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 8.4 and earlier, `UITableView dataSource` (and `delegate`) are defined as `assign` properties (as of iOS 9 they are `weak`).

The problem is that you `alloc/init` an object and set it to this `assign` property.

At the end of the block, the `ShoppingListDataSource` will be released and then deallocated because there are no more strong references to it. So now the table view's `dataSource` is left pointing to garbage. That's the cause of the error message.

The solution is to keep a strong reference to the `ShoppingListDataSource` instance in an ivar or somewhere.